# Excel - How do you create different number of columns in each row?

Tags: excel, formatting

[image: I would like to make an excel sheet similar to the one here]

the top row contains month, each month is split into columns. 
How do I do that in Excel?

Comment: Use merge and centre

Comment: sorry for the newbie question but for example, the month of September, where would I enter the weeks and how do I merge them with the month column?

Comment: I would calculate the week from the dates and the dates, for example, by finding the first Monday in January and working from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click and drag 4 cells in first row and merge them,similarly you can do for all the months and then in second row you can write numbers 1-12.
If you want I can share a google sheets link for your reference.

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xLsrt9aE55G3OgIeAv4zy5JNekpkImR9fmylzlyKk5Y/edit?usp=sharing)